# How do I represent a mathematical function in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I want to write something like

> F : X ----> Y
>
> x |---> 2x

in LaTeX where the

> x |---> 2x

appears directly below

> F : X ----> Y

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @SAM English is not my native language, hope now it's better.

Answer (score 5):

This should be the right approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
F\colon & X \rightarrow Y \\
        & x \mapsto 2x
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer a different alignment move the `&`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
F\colon X & \rightarrow Y \\
        x & \mapsto 2x
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also prefer longer arrows, use `\longrightarrow` and `\longmapsto`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
F\colon X & \longrightarrow Y \\
        x & \longmapsto 2x
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also substitute `\rightarrow` with `\to`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by `|`, but for aligning equations, the `align`-environment is often used. Here it will align at the arrow since I put `&` right in front of the `\Rightarrow`. This is explained further in the documentation.

Note that you can always locate the documentation using the command-line/terminal by writing `texdoc amsmath`, and that works for any package. The documentation is also available at http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath

It might sound tedious to look up the documentation for various small problems/features, but the package documentations tend to be well-written and easy to browse. Also, it will at the same time help you to understand how LaTeX works.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    F: x &\Rightarrow Y\\
       x &\Rightarrow 2x
\end{align}
\end{document}
```